# Google chrome Developer Tools & 'known' exception

Tags: jquery, angularjs, developer-tools, web-developer-toolbar

My developer tools session pauses while the page load. I see it happens while loading jquery and angular.js. I don't see any error afterwards.  See the secreenshot (stack) below.

[image: Jquery exception]

It is look like this is just a check for sizzle.js. Should I concern?

[image: Angular error]

Looks like it is looking for locale module.

If these errors are ok, how can I bypass these two errors in Developer Tools as I had to resume every time the page reloads.

Comment: The CSS selector seems wrong. It looks like some jQuery selector instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a pause on exception disable feature.
https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints#js_exceptions

Comment: This link is now broken. Please repost the relevant section of text also.